# Can you get RTX for Minecraft on Xbox?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Is there anyway I get the RTX without having a PC?

Answer (score 5):

## No

RTX requires having a PC and graphics card that supports it.

[Info from Minecraft themselves.](https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/360052771272-About-the-1-16-200-Update-for-Windows-10-)

Answer (score 0):

No, though Mojang Studios is planning to add similar ray-tracing graphical features to Minecraft on both PS5 and Xbox Series X.

Trailer:

No official release date at this time.